# Can I tell black to ignore formatting long lines in my python script

Tags: python, format

I am used to using flake8 for linting. Flake8 has a setup.cfg file where I can tell it to ignore line length. I would also like to tell my fixer(`black`) to not reformat long lines. How can I configure black to do everything it normally does except fix line length?

https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a way to completely ignore line length, but Black [does use a configuration file](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#configuration-via-a-file) (`pyproject.toml`) in which you can specify max line length, so setting `line-length` reasonably (or ridiculously) long should help.

Example:

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 160
```

Notes:

- This may re-format intentionally split lines into longer lines. Black is still opinionated.
- The values available in the configuration file are "the same as long names of options on the command line" [according to the docs](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#configuration-format). (This list isn't available in the documentation, but can be found by running `black --help`.)